# Problem with posting the message using php

Tags: php, oauth

I have successfully come up to the `access_token` step along with final `oauth_token` and `oauth_token_secret` values.

Now I'm trying to access the Post method given by Yammer API with following request :

```
https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/?
body=MyMessage&
oauth_consumer_key=Myconsumerkey&
oauth_nonce=1825bbc0f0a2875eb94bdb4d51c0638b&
oauth_signature=JzG4DCWxuP%2B7xT7u3tFZ2zCC8%2BI%3D&
oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&
oauth_timestamp=1257761059&
oauth_token=Myfinaloauthtoken&
oauth_version=1.0
```

But I'm getting "Invalid OAuth signature" error.

Can somebody help me in this.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are missing %26 from the end of your signature.  I realise this was an old post but did you manage to get a Yammer post message working?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have some strange characters in the oauth_signature:

JzG4DCWxuP ***%2B*** 7xT7u3tFZ2zCC8 ***%2B*** I ***%3D*** &

Check where those are coming from.

Comment: Thanks Piskvor for your quick reply..
Those characters are because of HMAC-SHA1 signature method.. but the same request or signature is working fine if I want to view the messages.

Problem is for posting the message.

Can you please tell some sample post message request for Yammer in php?

Answer (score 0):

Tricky to say without seeing the code you're running, but check these things:

- are the post body parameters all included in the key/values use to generate the signature?
- are you including only the base URL in the signature base string? (i.e. the bit upto, but not including the '?')
- are you including the HTTP method (`POST` in this case) in the signature base string?